# how can I use relative "who" here?

Tags: relative-clauses

I have 2 sentences:

> The girl gave me a dictionary. She is very beautiful.

Can I use the relative clause as follow?

> "The girl who is beautiful gave me a dictionary"

or can I write like this:

> The girl who gave me a dictionary is beautiful.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Both are grammatical, but obviously used in different circumstances.

Comment: Is the difference is to emphasize the action?

Comment: No, the difference is absolutely everything. One sentence says, the girl is beautiful. The other says, the girl gave you a book. One is about the girl. The other about the book. The two sentences couldn't be more different if they tried. Subordinate clause is subordinate. Main clause is main.

Comment: What the correct answer could be If I were asked to write the "relative clause" with those two sentences?

Comment: You may find our sister site, *English Language Learners* helpful, for this type of question.